# Problems with iOS App Transport Security using ionic and cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, nsapptransportsecurity

I have problems to disable the iOS App Transport Security. 
First of all I am developing under windows 10 with visual Studio and I am trying to build the app on Mac OSX with XCode 7.1 via remotebuild from my windows machine.
I am using Ionic framework with cordova und the cordova-ios version 3.9.2

I searched alot how to fix my problem, but nothing worked. So far i tried to to edit appname-Info.plist file in appname/platform/ios/appname/ and added the following:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>myurl.com</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
      <false/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.0</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

I also tried this entry:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

Both options didn't work. I checked the appname-Info.plist file in the Xcode project on my Mac, but this didn't contain the NSAppTransportSecurity key. I tried adding it manually in Xcode and then everything worked just fine, but I changing this manual everytime is not an option.

So I also tried to add the following to the config.xml, which should also add the NSAppTransportSecurity to the appname-Inof.plist

```
     <platform name="ios">
<config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSAppTransportSecurity">
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
    </dict>
</config-file>
```

This didn't have any effect either.

Then I tried to use the cordova whitelist plugin following this tutorial:
http://docs.ionic.io/docs/cordova-whitelist. First I had the problem of using the newest whitelist version, because it does not work with cordova-ios v 3.9.2, only with 4.0.0 or newer. Then I found out, that I should use the whitelist version 1.0.0. First I could add it, because in VisualStudio it is not possible to speciy a version, when adding a custom plugin via a git repository. I tried to add it manually by using this command:

```
    cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.0
```

Adding the plugin worked, but the plugin is not configured in the config.xml of my project. I tried to add it there with the following line:

```
    <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1.0.0" src="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git" />
```

This also didn't work.

I tried many things and I am a bit confused now. What exactly is whitelist for and do i need to the current release if cordova-ios 3.9.2? Creates Whitelist the NSAppTransportSecurity key in the plist file?
Are there any other soultions to deal with the App Transport Security?
And what is the best way to deal with it and does anybody have an idea, why all solutions didn't work for me?

Best,
1ceman

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue with ios 9.x while developing cordova application using visual studio. This is totally related to IOS version. The easiest way of fixing this was by using a plugin. Take a look at [cordova-plugin-transport-security](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-transport-security). This solved Transport Security issue.

**Install**

Latest published version on npm (with Cordova CLI >= 5.0.0)

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-transport-security
```

Latest version from GitHub

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-transport-security.git
```

**Note:**
Platforms

Applies to iOS (9+) only.

Comment: Any idea how to get this to work on iOS 10? I continue getting the error when building out to iOS 10 devices.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the problem by using the ios-security plugin available at  https://github.com/robertklein/cordova-ios-security.git .
After using this plugin, the following key is added to the INfo.plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```